# How to create Postgres column to accept only text

Tags: postgresql

I am working with postgresql, I created a user table  with id and varchar fields.

```
CREATE TABLE "USER_MGMT"."USER"
(
    "USER_ID" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"USER_MGMT"."USER_SEQ"'::regclass),
    "FIRST_NAME" character varying(50)  COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "LAST_NAME" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL);
```

I want to store only string values in firstname not numeric  or special chars,

How can I do this?

Comment: add check constraint restricting the value. also probably please change the title - integers and special characters are strings

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded double quotes. The give you much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it

Comment: integer and characters come together are string.... "1a" etc

Comment: I would think long and hard about names like "Mary Anne", "François", and so on before doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use a check constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT fn_check CHECK (firstname ~ '^[A-Za-z ]+$')
```

But if you using Postgres in the context of an application, I really think you should be handling this in your app layer.  Actually, you would typically have several lines of defense, the first being UI side validation.  Any first names which someone made their way to the server would be taken out there, and the database would not need to have much logic to it.

Comment: @JQuery Then use a pattern which includes spaces `^[A-Za-z ]+$`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `check` constraint.  You can put in a list of characters you want using regular expressions.  For instance:

```
constraint chk_first_name check (first_name ~ '^[a-zA-Z]+$')
```

or to exclude certain values:

```
constraint chk_first_name check (not first_name ~ '[^0-9!@#$%^&*()]')
```

Answer (score 1):

smth like:

```
f=# CREATE TABLE "USER_MGMT"."USER"
(
    "USER_ID" SERIAL,
    "FIRST_NAME" character varying(50)  COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL CHECK ("FIRST_NAME" ~* '^[A-Za-z]+$'),
    "LAST_NAME" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
f=# insert into "USER_MGMT"."USER"("FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME") select 'a1','a';
ERROR:  new row for relation "USER" violates check constraint "USER_FIRST_NAME_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, a1, a).
```